# Read and add the values of same keys in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to add the values of a dictionary of the same key(s). In my example below, I strip off the version numbering for each keys while trying to add the values of the 'same' key.

```
item_dict = {
"item_C_v001" : 100,
"item_C_v002" : 100,
"item_A_v001" : 50,
"item_B_v001" : 75
}
```

My expected output should be:

```
"item_C_v" : 200,
"item_A_v" : 50,
"item_B_v" : 75
```

but instead I got the following if I tried printing `item_dict`:

```
"item_C_v" : 100,
"item_A_v" : 50,
"item_B_v" : 75
```

But the moment I tried to strip off, it seems that `item_C_v` is read once. How can I make it read 'twice' so that I can get `200` as the output for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`collections.defaultdict(int)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to group and sum the result by a desired part of a key which you can get with, for example, a regular expression. Something along these lines:

```
In [1]: from collections import defaultdict

In [2]: import re

In [3]: item_dict = {
   ...: "item_C_v001" : 100,
   ...: "item_C_v002" : 100,
   ...: "item_A_v001" : 50,
   ...: "item_B_v001" : 75
   ...: }

In [4]: result = defaultdict(int)

In [5]: for key, value in item_dict.items():
   ...:     result[re.search(r"(\w+?)\d+", key).group(1)] += value   

In [6]: dict(result)
Out[6]: {'item_A_v': 50, 'item_B_v': 75, 'item_C_v': 200}
```

---

You can approach extracting the desired part of a key differently - with the [`str.partition()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition):

```
>>> key = "item_C_v001"
>>> "".join(key.partition("_v")[:-1])
'item_C_v'
```

Or, simply via slicing, if the length of the substring before the digits or the number of digits at the end of the string is constant:

```
>>> key = "item_C_v001"
>>> key[:8]
'item_C_v'
>>> key[:-3]
'item_C_v'
```

Or, by right-stripping the digits:

```
>>> import string
>>> key.rstrip(string.digits)
'item_C_v'
```

Comment: Cool, was not aware of using `string` module. Perhaps I am trying to reduce the use of any modules. Same goes for `partition`. Will try incorporating the use of `defaultdict` since I had that module. Just that I am not very strong in using regex

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate the original dictionary and append to the new dictionary the new keys, if the key already exists, add the current value to the original value.

```
item_dict = {
"item_C_v001" : 100,
"item_C_v002" : 100,
"item_A_v001" : 50,
"item_B_v001" : 75
}

new_dict = {}

for k, v in item_dict.items():
    k_new = k[:-3]
    new_dict[k_new] = new_dict[k_new] + v if k_new in new_dict.keys() else v

print (new_dict)

>>> {'item_A_v': 50, 'item_C_v': 200, 'item_B_v': 75}
```

Comment: Is there anyway that I can further refine `new_dict[k_new]` such that no '+' is used? Just curious about that. This may be a side question but how can I output in my code that `item_C_v` has been combined twice?

Comment: You can replace it with `new_dict[k_new] = new_dict.get(k_new, 0) + v`, using `get()` allows you to provide a default value. Or you can use `defaultdict(int)` and then the line would read `new_dict[k_new] += v`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.groupby()` to collect all the similar keys and then construct a new dictionary summing up all the group values, e.g.:

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> {gk: sum(item_dict[k] for k in g) for gk, g in it.groupby(item_dict, lambda k: k[:-3])}
{'item_A_v': 50, 'item_B_v': 75, 'item_C_v': 200}
```

@alecxe describes several methods to getting the desired part of the key, above uses `key[-3]`.

There was a request to get both the `count` and `sum`, which you could implement in a simple loop and manage a counter but here's one way of doing it:

```
>>> from collections import deque
>>> {key: deque(enumerate(it.accumulate(item_dict[k] for k in g), 1), maxlen=1).pop()
...     for key, g in it.groupby(item_dict, lambda key: key[:-3])}
{'item_A_v': (1, 50), 'item_B_v': (1, 75), 'item_C_v': (2, 200)}
```